# Uncaught TypeError: SP.ClientContext is not a constructor

Tags: office-365

I am trying to fetch list items from my list in SharePoint online. But, I am getting a single error. I tried a lot, but unable to resolve the issue. Please someone tell me any workaround for this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
function retriveListItem()  
{      
            var siteUrl = '/sites/NewWorkSite';
            var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);  
            var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Questions1List');  
            var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();  
            caml.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='QuestionNumber' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>");  
            returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);  
            context.load(returnedItems);  
            context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);  
}  

    // Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
    // code runs.
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retriveListItem);

function onSucceededCallback(sender, args)  
{  
            var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();  
            //Formulate HTML from the list items   
            var MainResult = 'Items in the Divisions list: <br><br>';  
            //Loop through all the items   
            while (enumerator.moveNext())  
            {  

                var listItem = enumerator.get_current();  
                var qNo= listItem.get_item("QuestionNumber");   
                var qst = listItem.get_item("Question");   
                var optionA = listItem.get_item("OptionA");         
                var optionB = listItem.get_item("OptionB");
                var optionC = listItem.get_item("OptionC");
                var optionD = listItem.get_item("OptionD");

                        $('#qDiv').append("<label>" + qNo+ "." + "</label>&nbsp" + "<label id='qts'>" + qst + "</label>" + "</br>" 
                        + "<label>A: </label>&nbsp" + "<input id='one' class='rdBtn' type='radio' name = '" + qNo+ "' value = 'A'/>&nbsp" + optionA  + "&nbsp</br>"
                        + "<label>B: </label>&nbsp" + "<input id='two' class='rdBtn' type='radio' name = '" + qNo+ "' value = 'B'/>&nbsp" + optionB + "</br>"
                        + "<label>C: </label>&nbsp" + "<input id='three' class='rdBtn' type='radio' name = '" + qNo+ "' value = 'C'/>&nbsp" + optionC + "</br>"
                        + "<label>D: </label>&nbsp" + "<input id='four' class='rdBtn' type='radio' name = '" + qNo+ "' value = 'D'/>&nbsp" + optionD + "</br>" + "</br>");
            }  

    }  
                //This function fires when the query fails   
function onFailedCallback(sender, args)  
{  
                //Formulate HTML to display details of the error   
                var markup = '<p>The request failed: <br>';  
                markup1 = 'Message: ' + args.get_message() + '<br>';  
                //Display the details   
                alert(markup1);
} 

retriveListItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

If SP.ClientContext() executes before SP.js loaded in the page then the error will come.I modify your code so that the retriveListItem() method will call after SP.js loaded successfully.

```
  function retriveListItem()  
    {      
                var siteUrl = '/sites/NewWorkSite';
                var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);  
                var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Questions1List');  
                var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();  
                caml.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='QuestionNumber' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>");  
                returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);  
                context.load(returnedItems);  
                context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);  
    }  
    ///You can use ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded method which will call the method after sp.js filed loaded in the page 

        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retriveListItem, “sp.js”);

    function onSucceededCallback(sender, args)  
    {  
                var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();  
                //Formulate HTML from the list items   
                var MainResult = 'Items in the Divisions list: <br><br>';  
                //Loop through all the items   
                while (enumerator.moveNext())  
                {  

                    var listItem = enumerator.get_current();  
                    var qNo= listItem.get_item("QuestionNumber");   
                    var qst = listItem.get_item("Question");   
                    var optionA = listItem.get_item("OptionA");         
                    var optionB = listItem.get_item("OptionB");
                    var optionC = listItem.get_item("OptionC");
                    var optionD = listItem.get_item("OptionD");

                            $('#qDiv').append("<label>" + qNo+ "." + "</label>&nbsp" + "<label id='qts'>" + qst + "</label>" + "</br>" 
                            + "<label>A: </label>&nbsp" + "<input id='one' class='rdBtn' type='radio' name = '" + qNo+ "' value = 'A'/>&nbsp" + optionA  + "&nbsp</br>"
                            + "<label>B: </label>&nbsp" + "<input id='two' class='rdBtn' type='radio' name = '" + qNo+ "' value = 'B'/>&nbsp" + optionB + "</br>"
                            + "<label>C: </label>&nbsp" + "<input id='three' class='rdBtn' type='radio' name = '" + qNo+ "' value = 'C'/>&nbsp" + optionC + "</br>"
                            + "<label>D: </label>&nbsp" + "<input id='four' class='rdBtn' type='radio' name = '" + qNo+ "' value = 'D'/>&nbsp" + optionD + "</br>" + "</br>");
                }  

        }  
                    //This function fires when the query fails   
    function onFailedCallback(sender, args)  
    {  
                    //Formulate HTML to display details of the error   
                    var markup = '<p>The request failed: <br>';  
                    markup1 = 'Message: ' + args.get_message() + '<br>';  
                    //Display the details   
                    alert(markup1);
    } 

    retriveListItem();
```

Comment: Hi! I tried it. But still getting the error.

Comment: Check your browser debugger, is the script SP.js load to browser correctly?

Comment: Yes, it loads correctly. The file is shown in the resources.